# How to center the text above a rectangle inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to center the text "Text Box 1" and "Text Box 2" above the rectangle?

**My Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (5,5) node[above] {Text Box 1};

        \draw[red] (1,1) rectangle (3,3) node[above] {Text Box 2};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

**My Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way in simple cases, as this one you post, is to tell tikz where to write the node, choosing the midpoint of the side of the square, so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (5,5) node[above] at (2.5,5) {Text Box 1};
        
        \draw[red] (1,1) rectangle (3,3) node[above] at (2,3) {Text Box 2};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Is there another way? xPos=0.5 or something?

Comment: There is a command for nodes       `midway`      but works better for segments and curves.